# Exception: connect: does not exist (Connection refused) when trying to connect to TCP socket in Haskell

Tags: macos, sockets, haskell, tcp

#### Context

I was following the [tutorial on writing a TCP server last week in Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/sockets-and-syslog.html). Everything went well and I had the final version of it working and was able to send messages between the TCP client and server.

Then, I wanted to write my own TCP server for a small TicTacToe game that I coded. I started out writing the server and client and played around with it a bit, it worked so far that the server was able to accept connections, but there was no real interaction yet.

Now it gets a bit awkward, because after I turned my Mac off and tried to reboot it again, it wouldn't boot any more. I fiddled around all Friday to do a backup from Single User Mode and reinstalled Mac OS. After a successful reinstallation, all my data was still there, so I didn't need the backup after all.

Anyway, today I am turning back to my TicTacToe-server but it doesn't work any more. Or, at least the client can't connect to it any more.

#### TL;DR

I wrote a TCP server for a TicTacToe game inspired by the [tutorial in Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/sockets-and-syslog.html) but am getting a `*** Exception: connect: does not exist (Connection refused)` error when trying to connect to the server. The same happens with the vanilla code from the mentioned tutorial.

Note that I can still connect to the servers using `telnet`. I'm pretty sure the issue isn't with the code but rather on system level as the same code was working before I had the trouble with my machine (see above) and I am still using the identical code from the tutorial in RWH.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, the problem can be solved by connecting to `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`. Apparently some bindings were changed when my system broke down and got reinstalled, so `ghc` doesn't know how to resolve `localhost` (or something like that....)

Comment: I would bet that if you run wireshark you'd see the proper DNS request for localhost does not resolve - what does `ping localhost` say?  What do those packets look like?  Perhaps 'localhost' is resolving to an IPv6 address and you have v6 issues?

Comment: Same problem, It's just Haskell issue on my system (OSX), other programs work just fine.